# Use eval in a restricted scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, eval

OK, let me explain what I need:

- I want the user to be able to `eval` his own valid JS/jQuery statements
- Access to elements must be restricted - meaning: let's say object `X` should not be available, but object `Y` should.

How should I go about that?

Comment: Write your own Javascript engine and DOM layer?

Comment: Can't you _undefine_ objects/functions you don't want to expose (prepending such script to code you have to eval and restoring them after it has been executed)? It's not such safe but if you trust your user enough to execute code they enter...

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi LOL. I'm that crazy that it'd normally be my first thought! (I've already created several interpreters/languages). However, isn't there any... smoother approach?

Comment: You can try to use something like this: `(function(){var window={};(function(){/*user code here*/})();})();`.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti That's what I was thinking but I'm not 100% sure how to go about it. That's why I wanted some ideas... :-)

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon what Ismael wrote isn't a bad starting point. `window` object contains most of things you may want to hide but also check for cookies and `document` (because it's still directly available if you redefine `window`). But don't forget they "see" your JavaScript then they may circumvent your tricks (directly accessing global objects).

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti That's what I'm playing with right now! ;-)

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel while that does hide the window object, it still let's you set on a global scope.

Comment: You would also have to bind `this` to something else than the global object, otherwise evaluated code can use it to get a reference back. And clobbering the global object will not allow filtering access to element `Y` but not to element `X`.

Comment: @DoXicK Then we can use the worst crime in Javascript: the `with` statement. Like this: `(function(){var window={};(function(){with(window){/*user code here*/}})();})();`

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel same story applies: `(function() { var window = {}; with(window) { test = "test"; } })(); console.log(test);`. Adding the extra scope does not make a difference btw

Comment: @DoXicK It's relatively safe to let the user make global vars. Try this: `(function() { var window = {}, x={}; with(x) { test = function(){return window;}; console.log(window); } })(); console.log(test());`

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel it's just a **starting point**. There is not only `window` object. For example `console` and `document` are also accessible directly (bypassing our _fake_ `window` declaration). This opens to cookies and DOM manipulation (for example). IMO central point is that in this way he can help users to avoid mistakes, security can't be enforced with `eval()`. Viable if user type some code and executes it in his own window, to absolutely avoid if code _may_ be executed also by someone else on another machine.

Comment: `(function(){var window={};(function(){with(window){/*user code here*/ console.log(self.window)}})();})();` -- broken. you could always do `var self,window,console,....={}` and use all those in your `with` statement. As Adriano says though ,you can't do security really.

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon Damn, I took too long. But I have a possible solution for you! Try this code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KqbIs

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon Sorry for the long delay. I made an update to the comment. It was 'leaking' out the `window` object, and wasn't doing what it was supposed to. There is still the problem with global vars, which I will take care later. I'm really interested in your question because I wanted to do something similar a long time ago, but never got the interest to actually do it.

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon I don't know if you are still interested in this question. But I have a better solution for you. Check this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vbtDj?editors=101 (ignore the poor documentation). I forked it from the last comment. Any question, don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Thanks a lot for the suggestions! Just noticed them (time differences issues?). I'll have a look into them! :-)